# Web Application using Ember.js and the dynamic ip backend API

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm playing more and more with Ember and I really like it.

It's new to me but guides are solid and everything.

I understand how to pin-point the API Server IP so Ember can use it, but I would like to make it more dynamic - The idea is that the API Server is on LAN network (or on dynamic IP WAN - but I don't want ddns for that)

The problem is that I currently have to type IP address then deploy and that version work with that one IP address. I would love to be able to type in IP address on first? and then use that ip as the endpoint for api server.

I'm more than sure this is somehow possible but I lack the examples out there.

I understand that there should be `application/index.js` route that would check some kind of 'store' to check if there is ip address with array that was saved locally in file?/cookie? and if there is one then somehow load that ip to the `adapters/application.js` host?

Answer (score 0):

Use an initializer if you have to initialize something.

Comment: ok this is a good start. I will them use ember-cli-cookie to store ip address and use initializer to read that ip address. but now the hard part would be inject that value into adapter host value... Also thanks for pointing to initializer I didn't know about them

Comment: where does the ip come from?

Comment: I would love to have initial page with textbox that you enter ipaddress by hand, then it would be saved to cookie (because i currently dont know where else I can store it), if cookie already there then that value would be read out of cookie.

Comment: Have you tried to set the host later?

this.get('store').adapterFor('application').set('host', newIP)

Comment: No, I didn't ! That could work ! Will check it out. Currently im testing the cookie write/read thing. Im trying to read cookie to setting menu also but that something I will try to figure out so i learn more ;-)

Comment: i tried it and i have error: ```_this.get(...) is undefined```

Comment: store: Ember.inject.service() at top resolve component not being able to get to store as its isolated. one problem down :-) back to orginal one.